# Rhombs/diamonds with questions marks instead of swedish characters in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I recently moved the content of a database from one host to another. And after that I get strange character like two rhombs or diamonds with questions marks inside instead of the swedish character `ä`.

I had this problem before at the first host and then I added this code and it worked fine

```
$query1 = "SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'";

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM arkitekturobjekt2 WHERE filnamn='{$namn}';";

$result = $db->query($query1);
$result = $db->query($query2);
```

If I remove the line with the `$query1` I only get one rhomb. How can I fix this?

EDIT:
This is my code and here is the strings puts together with the content from the DB in a loop. I tested to use `utf8_encode(string)` around `($row->byggnadstyp)` but then I get other strange character. But finally I tested to remove the `strtolower` then it's perfect, apart from that the first character isn't small. But I can live with that, but I would be interesting to know why I get this diamonds when I use `strtolower`. I use `utf8` everywhere and the files are set to utf8 without BOM.

```
$buildingInfo .= "<p>Byggnadstyp: " . strtolower ($row->byggnadstyp) . "</p>";
```

Comment: please post the table definition for arkitekturobjekt2

Comment: Where do I find that?

Comment: ```SHOW CREATE TABLE arkitekturobjekt2\G```

Comment: I made a print of the table definitions and I saw that I had 'byggnadstyp' text CHARACTER SET latin1, so I changed this to utf8_general_ci, but it didn't help! I also has DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 in the end after the ')'.

Comment: When I google about php strtolower and encoding it seems like it dosen't care about swedish character like 'å ä ö'. I guess this is the problem and ther are ways to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add this to your mysql config:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8


[mysqld]
default-character-set = utf8    
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
skip-character-set-client-handshake=1
```

The last line (skip-character-set-client-handshake=1) may not be needed.

If you don't have access to the config file, you could check out this [help page](https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Garbled_data). It basically boils down to send the command

```
SET NAMES 'UTF8';
```

at the beginning of a connection. This is however similar to what you do already.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry, but I don't understand how I should add this code. What mysql config?! I can change the PHP code or change the database with PHPmyAdmin. Please explain!

Comment: i don't know phpmyadmin well. The my.cnf file is located on the server where the database runs. It contains the configuration of the database server itself. If you do not have access to it, I don't think my approach will help.

Comment: No, I have not access to file file.

Comment: See my added content. Maybe it helps to go through the wiki help site

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help! It removed one diamond of two and more diamonds showed up at other places. Strange! Why just this 'ä' and not other swedish character like 'ö' ??